# How to prevent Swiper.JS from transitioning middle slide between two slides?

Tags: javascript, carousel, swiper.js

I am using Swiper.js when I navigate from slide 1 to slide 5; then all the slides between slide 1 and slide 5 are rapidly slid through. ([CODEPEN HERE](https://codepen.io/hibasirpayenda/pen/BarYYry))

```
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    swiperOptions: {
      loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 5000 
      },
      speed: 500,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How do I "skip" the slides between slides 1 and 5, so I get a smooth slide from slide 1 to slide 5 without transitioning middle slides in between?

If this isn't possible, what other library do you recommend that has this feature?